# Mail sending service required for android app

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

Is there any mail sending api/service for android applications apart from Java mail API?
Right now I am using javamail API and  after testing it I thought its working fine but actually its getting blocked when used from some other network despite of allowing access for less secured apps in Gmail setting of that particular account.
I don't mind even if some paid service is available for few bucks.

This is not required for bulk mails. Required for functionality like feedback of app.(I don't want to use firebase and all because there is no mechanism for login in my app)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to embed mail server credentials in your app, it's too easy to abuse them.  Better to create a web service to accept the feedback and then use JavaMail on the server to send it, if you still even need email.  You can limit the functionality of the web service to make it harder to abuse.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your response. I agree with your solution and will try to do the same.
Thanks